# Flattening a list desiring a specific format

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have the following list:

```
l={{{1},{2}},{{3}},{{4},{5}}};
```

How can I flatten this such that I get:

```
{{1,2},{3},{4,5}}
```

I tried `Flatten[l, 1]` but that gives:

```
{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Flatten[#, 1] & /@ l
```

> {{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}}

Answer (score 4):

```
Flatten[l, {3, 1}]
```

> {{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}}

Also

```
Flatten /@ l
Flatten[l, {{3, 1}}]
Join @@@ l
```

all give

> {{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5}}